# How to convert System.Drawing.Color to ClosedXML.Excel.XLColor in C#

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml, system.drawing.color

I am working with [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) and the background color of a specific cell could be set like the following code.

```
using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
{
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
    worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World!";
    worksheet.Cell("A1").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = ClosedXML.Excel.XLColor.AliceBlue;
    //  Fill background color as AliceBlue.
    workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
}
```

My question is:

Is there appropriate method to convert System.Drawing.Color to ClosedXML.Excel.XLColor?

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used ClosedXml but [the fine manual](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Using-Colors) shows many ways an XLColor can be created. I picked on the first when writing this answer initially:

```
var c = Color.Red;
var xlc = XLColor.FromArgb(c.A, c.R, c,G, c.B);
```

@FrancoisBotha helpfully pointed out that there is an overload that takes the color directly:

```
var c = Color.Red;
var xlc = XLColor.FromColor(c);
```

You can see the other ways in the manual..

Comment: `XLColor.FromColor(c)` is even easier.

Comment: Hah, for some reason I didn't notice that one - updated, thanks Francois